# html5 video not starting

Tags: html, video

I'm trying to use a video as a background for my div.
I've loaded the mp4 version of the video into my server, inside the public folder.
When I load the page the video doesn't seem to be there since it's all white, but when I try another video from another website this works fine.
Is there something I need to do while loading the video into my server or there is something wrong with my code?

```
<body>
 <video id="bgvid" controls="controls" autoplay muted>
     <source src="http://MyUrl/public/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
 <div class="overlap">
     <div class="overlapalign"><div class="overlaptext">OVER TEXT</div></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you open the console do you have any errors at all?

Comment: all clear, no errors!

Comment: If you open the console's network tab does it show that the video has loaded without problems?

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ so that we can try to see what's wrong?

Comment: i've just tried to open the video directly with its own url. I get the following error: HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Answer (score 1):

Try including this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('video').get(0).play();
                                        });
</script>
```

Html5 "autoplay" doesn't work with some browsers.